# Can anyone suggest a method to identify the compression ratio used by an image compression app like whatsapp .

Tags: decompress

Let us say i have the original image and compressed image and let us assume whatsapp uses jpeg compression algo , then is it possible to find out what compression ratio is used (as in , is it fixed or differs on an image by image basis) , and how is compression ratio related to the quantization matrix

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone suggest a method to identify the compression ratio used by
>   an image compression app like whatsapp

Yes. Reverse engineer the code that performs the image compression.